# Passing several strings to other Activites

Tags: android, android-activity

I have

```
EditText editTextSignUpUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_user_name);
EditText editTextSignUpPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_password);
EditText editTextSignUpEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_email_address);
```

and

```
 String messageUserName = intent.getStringExtra(SignUp.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 String messagePassword = intent.getStringExtra(SignUp.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
 String messageEmailAddress = intent.getStringExtra(SignUp.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

of course all three strings show up as messageEmailAddress.

how can i pass each string separately to the next activity (and therefor to the database)?
please and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to do it.

- Using **intents**

In your Activity, create an Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("password",editTextSignUpPassword.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("username",editTextSignUpUserName.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the other Activity, you can get those values like :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String messageUserName = extras.getString("username");
    String messagePassword = extras.getString("password");
}
```

---

- You can declare them as **`static`** variables and then in your other class you may access them like  `Activity1.messageUserName` , `Actvity1.messagePassword` and then insert them in the database or do whatever you want to.

  public static String messagePassword;
  public static String messageUserName;

  messagePassword = editTextSignUpPassword.getText().toString();

Then, in all the other Activities, you can access them as **`YourMainActivty.messagePassword`**.

***EDIT : *** Implementation of your code :

```
  EditText editTextSignUpUserName;
  EditText editTextSignUpPassword;
  @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
  editTextSignUpUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_user_name);
  editTextSignUpPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sign_up_password); 
   }

   public void onClickSignUp(View view)
  { Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class); 
  String signUpUserName = editTextSignUpUserName.getText().toString();
  String signUpPassword = editTextSignUpPassword.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra("username", signUpUserName); 
  intent.putExtra("password", signUpPassword);
  startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Then in **`SignIn.class`**,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String messageUserName = extras.getString("username");
    String messagePassword = extras.getString("password");
}
```

Comment: I have added the code in my answer. Please do have a look at it.

Comment: You are welcome! and yeah, don't forget to accept the answer if did work for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is, passing these values through intent to next activity,
You can do this on the click of button or on the event where you are moving to next activity,

```
String username = sign_up_user_name.getText().toString();
String password = editTextSignUpPassword.getText().toString();
String email = editTextSignUpEmailAddress.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("username",username);
i.putExtra("password",password);
i.putExtra("email",email);
this.getContext.startActivity(i);
```

Then in the nextActivity

```
String username = this.getIntent.getStringExtra("username");
String password = this.getIntent.getStringExtra("password");
String email = this.getIntent.getStringExtra("email");
```